# My java code resulted in a double spaced output

Tags: java

I'm doing an assignment in MyProgrammingLab for JAVA and my code resulted in an error. The output is double spaced and I can't figure out why. I thought it might have something to do with the 'System.out.println' from reading other discussions, but I was not successful when I left off the 'ln'. This is my first course in JAVA. I apologize if the solution is obvious. Any hint would be helpful. Thank you!

```
CODELAB ANALYSIS: LOGICAL ERROR(S)
Problems Detected:
     ⇒     The contents of your standard output is incorrect.

Given the following was entered from the keyboard:
!!!!!If you built your letter counter properly it will not count anything 
but proper letters@@@@@@.
AlsO The DegRee OF captilization SHOULD NOT AFFECT YOUR COUNTER in any way 
shape or form.
Multiple sentences on one line are fine. As long as the line ends with a 
period.
aaaaa bbbbb ttttt uuuuuuuuuu.
Goodbye

you displayed:
...
The letter B occurred 2 times in the sentence.

The letter C occurred 2 times in the sentence.

The letter E occurred 7 times in the sentence.

The letter F occurred 1 times in the sentence.

...
instead of:
...
The letter B occurred 2 times in the sentence.
The letter C occurred 2 times in the sentence.
The letter E occurred 7 times in the sentence.
The letter F occurred 1 times in the sentence.
The letter G occurred 1 times in the sentence.
The letter H occurred 1 times in the sentence.
The letter I occurred 5 times in the sentence.
The letter L occurred 6 times in the sentence.
The letter N occurred 5 times in the sentence.
...

     ⇒     Failed 4 out of 4 test runs.

Failed Test Run #1

     ⇒     The contents of your standard output is incorrect.
     ⇒     There is an error in your prompts.

Hide Invisibles
Expected Result:
```

> Enter·a·sentence·ending·with·a·period·or·anything·not·ending·in·a·period·to·end:
>
> The·letter·A·occurred·4·times·in·the·sentence.↵
>       The·letter·B·occurred·1·times·in·the·sentence.↵
>       The·letter·C·occurred·1·times·in·the·sentence.↵
>       The·letter·E·occurred·9·times·in·the·sentence.↵
>       The·letter·H·occurred·3·times·in·the·sentence.↵
>       The·letter·I·occurred·1·times·in·the·sentence.↵
>       The·letter·N·occurred·4·times·in·the·sentence.↵
>       The·letter·O·occurred·2·times·in·the·sentence.↵
>       The·letter·R·occurred·4·times·in·the·sentence.↵
>       The·letter·S·occurred·4·times·in·the·sentence.↵
>       The·letter·T·occurred·1·times·in·the·sentence.↵
>       The·letter·U·occurred·1·times·in·the·sentence.↵
>       The·letter·V·occurred·2·times·in·the·sentence.↵
>       The·letter·W·occurred·1·times·in·the·sentence.↵ Enter·a·sentence·ending·with·a·period·or·anything·not·ending·in·a·period·to·end:
>       The·letter·A·occurred·15·times·in·the·sentence.↵
>       The·letter·B·occurred·5·times·in·the·sentence.↵
>       The·letter·C·occurred·10·times·in·the·sentence.↵ Enter·a·sentence·ending·with·a·period·or·anything·not·ending·in·a·period·to·end:
>       The·letter·Z·occurred·5·times·in·the·sentence.↵ Enter·a·sentence·ending·with·a·period·or·anything·not·ending·in·a·period·to·end:
>       The·letter·G·occurred·8·times·in·the·sentence.↵
>       The·letter·R·occurred·9·times·in·the·sentence.↵ Enter·a·sentence·ending·with·a·period·or·anything·not·ending·in·a·period·to·end:
>       The·letter·A·occurred·1·times·in·the·sentence.↵
>       The·letter·C·occurred·1·times·in·the·sentence.↵
>       The·letter·D·occurred·1·times·in·the·sentence.↵
>       The·letter·E·occurred·4·times·in·the·sentence.↵
>       The·letter·G·occurred·2·times·in·the·sentence.↵
>       The·letter·H·occurred·3·times·in·the·sentence.↵
>       The·letter·I·occurred·2·times·in·the·sentence.↵
>       The·letter·L·occurred·4·times·in·the·sentence.↵
>       The·letter·M·occurred·1·times·in·the·sentence.↵
>       The·letter·N·occurred·4·times·in·the·sentence.↵
>       The·letter·O·occurred·5·times·in·the·sentence.↵
>       The·letter·P·occurred·1·times·in·the·sentence.↵
>       The·letter·R·occurred·3·times·in·the·sentence.↵
>       The·letter·S·occurred·4·times·in·the·sentence.↵
>       The·letter·T·occurred·5·times·in·the·sentence.↵
>       The·letter·U·occurred·2·times·in·the·sentence.↵
>       The·letter·Y·occurred·1·times·in·the·sentence.↵ Enter·a·sentence·ending·with·a·period·or·anything·not·ending·in·a·period·to·end:
>       The·letter·A·occurred·9·times·in·the·sentence.↵
>       The·letter·B·occurred·2·times·in·the·sentence.↵
>       The·letter·C·occurred·3·times·in·the·sentence.↵
>       The·letter·E·occurred·24·times·in·the·sentence.↵
>       The·letter·F·occurred·3·times·in·the·sentence.↵
>       The·letter·G·occurred·7·times·in·the·sentence.↵
>       The·letter·H·occurred·14·times·in·the·sentence.↵
>       The·letter·I·occurred·12·times·in·the·sentence.↵
>       The·letter·K·occurred·1·times·in·the·sentence.↵
>       The·letter·L·occurred·7·times·in·the·sentence.↵
>       The·letter·M·occurred·2·times·in·the·sentence.↵
>       The·letter·N·occurred·10·times·in·the·sentence.↵
>       The·letter·O·occurred·9·times·in·the·sentence.↵
>       The·letter·P·occurred·4·times·in·the·sentence.↵
>       The·letter·Q·occurred·1·times·in·the·sentence.↵
>       The·letter·R·occurred·5·times·in·the·sentence.↵
>       The·letter·S·occurred·9·times·in·the·sentence.↵
>       The·letter·T·occurred·22·times·in·the·sentence.↵
>       The·letter·U·occurred·8·times·in·the·sentence.↵
>       The·letter·V·occurred·1·times·in·the·sentence.↵
>       The·letter·W·occurred·3·times·in·the·sentence.↵
>       The·letter·X·occurred·1·times·in·the·sentence.↵
>       The·letter·Y·occurred·5·times·in·the·sentence.↵ Enter·a·sentence·ending·with·a·period·or·anything·not·ending·in·a·period·to·end:
>       The·letter·A·occurred·6·times·in·the·sentence.↵
>       The·letter·B·occurred·1·times·in·the·sentence.↵
>       The·letter·C·occurred·1·times·in·the·sentence.↵
>       The·letter·D·occurred·2·times·in·the·sentence.↵
>       The·letter·E·occurred·7·times·in·the·sentence.↵
>       The·letter·G·occurred·2·times·in·the·sentence.↵
>       The·letter·H·occurred·5·times·in·the·sentence.↵
>       The·letter·I·occurred·6·times·in·the·sentence.↵
>       The·letter·L·occurred·2·times·in·the·sentence.↵
>       The·letter·M·occurred·2·times·in·the·sentence.↵
>       The·letter·N·occurred·5·times·in·the·sentence.↵
>       The·letter·O·occurred·5·times·in·the·sentence.↵
>       The·letter·P·occurred·2·times·in·the·sentence.↵
>       The·letter·R·occurred·4·times·in·the·sentence.↵
>       The·letter·S·occurred·2·times·in·the·sentence.↵
>       The·letter·T·occurred·12·times·in·the·sentence.↵
>       The·letter·U·occurred·3·times·in·the·sentence.↵
>       The·letter·W·occurred·2·times·in·the·sentence.↵
>       The·letter·Y·occurred·1·times·in·the·sentence.↵ Enter·a·sentence·ending·with·a·period·or·anything·not·ending·in·a·period·to·end:↵

Your Code's Actual Result:

> Enter·a·sentence·ending·with·a·period·or·anything·not·ending·in·a·period·to·end:
>       The·letter·A·occurred·4·times·in·the·sentence.↵
>       ↵
>       The·letter·B·occurred·1·times·in·the·sentence.↵
>       ↵
>       The·letter·C·occurred·1·times·in·the·sentence.↵
>       ↵
>       The·letter·E·occurred·9·times·in·the·sentence.↵
>       ↵
>       The·letter·H·occurred·3·times·in·the·sentence.↵
>       ↵
>       The·letter·I·occurred·1·times·in·the·sentence.↵
>       ↵
>       The·letter·N·occurred·4·times·in·the·sentence.↵
>       ↵
>       The·letter·O·occurred·2·times·in·the·sentence.↵
>       ↵
>       The·letter·R·occurred·4·times·in·the·sentence.↵
>       ↵
>       The·letter·S·occurred·4·times·in·the·sentence.↵
>       ↵
>       The·letter·T·occurred·1·times·in·the·sentence.↵
>       ↵
>       The·letter·U·occurred·1·times·in·the·sentence.↵
>       ↵
>       The·letter·V·occurred·2·times·in·the·sentence.↵
>       ↵
>       The·letter·W·occurred·1·times·in·the·sentence.↵
>       ↵
>       ↵

Here is my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class LetterFreq
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        String input = "";
        int a[] = new int[26];
        System.out.print("Enter a sentence ending with a period or anything not ending in a period to end:");
        input = sc.nextLine();
        char[] c = input.toCharArray();
        for(int i = 0; i < c.length; i++)
        {
            if(Character.isDigit(c[i]))
            {
                System.out.println();
                System.exit(0);
            }
            if(Character.isLetter(c[i]))
            {
                if(Character.isLowerCase(c[i]))
                    c[i] = Character.toUpperCase(c[i]);
                int index = c[i] - 'A';
                int b = a[index];
                b++;
                a[index] = b;
            }
        }
        for(int i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
        {
            if(a[i] > 0)
            {
                System.out.println("The letter " + (char)(i + 'A') + " occurred " + a[i] + " times in the sentence.");
                System.out.println();
            }
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**:
When I remove the 'System.out.println();' that appears after the one with '"The letter "', I get another output error: 
    CODELAB ANALYSIS: LOGICAL ERROR(S)

```
Problems Detected:
     ⇒     The contents of your standard output is incorrect.

Given the following was entered from the keyboard:
!!!!!If you built your letter counter properly it will not count anything
```

but proper letters@@@@@@.
    AlsO The DegRee OF captilization SHOULD NOT AFFECT YOUR COUNTER in any way shape or form.
    Multiple sentences on one line are fine. As long as the line ends with a period.
    aaaaa bbbbb ttttt uuuuuuuuuu.
    Goodbye

```
you displayed:
...

instead of:
...
Enter a sentence ending with a period or anything not ending in a period to 
end:The letter A occurred 7 times in the sentence.
The letter C occurred 3 times in the sentence.
The letter D occurred 2 times in the sentence.
The letter E occurred 7 times in the sentence.
The letter F occurred 4 times in the sentence.
The letter G occurred 1 times in the sentence.
The letter H occurred 3 times in the sentence.
The letter I occurred 4 times in the sentence.
The letter L occurred 3 times in the sentence.
...

     ⇒     Failed 4 out of 4 test runs.



     ⇒     The contents of your standard output is incorrect.
     ⇒     There is an error in your prompts.
```

The output for my code shows up far down the page on the test runs, but the double-spacing has been corrected. I'm not sure how to fix the error mentioned above. Thoughts?

Comment: Well yes - look at your code: `System.out.println("The letter " + (char)(i + 'A') + " occurred " + a[i] + " times in the sentence.");
                System.out.println();` What do you think that second `System.out.println()` is doing?

Comment: You're getting "double-spaced" because that's what you're explicitely declaring with the line: `System.out.println();`. Remove it, and you'll remove the double-spacing.

Comment: Thank you Jon Skeet and AntonH. I edited my post. I was able to fix the double-spacing problem, but still have an error somewhere. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`println` adds the newline character at the end of your output, and you have two of them - one with the output you want, and another one after it. Remove it, and you should be OK.

Comment: Mureinik, I appreciate your instruction. I will make note of 'println'.

Answer (score 0):

Look at your code:

```
System.out.println("The letter " + (char)(i + 'A') + " occurred " + a[i] + " times in the sentence."); 
System.out.println();
```

What do you think that second `System.out.println()` is doing?

You're getting "double-spaced" because that's what you're explicitely declaring with the line:

```
System.out.println();
```

Remove it, and you'll remove the double-spacing.

Comment: Thank you sudo. Double-spacing removed. I will remember in future.